# In Latex Table Printing one of two variables

Tags: variables, latex

I have a table in Latex in one of the columns I want to print `%itemnotes%` unless the field `%itemnotes%` is blank or undefined (i.e. length of `%itemnotes%` is not zero).   If `%itemnotes%` is blank I want to print the field `%description%`.

Is this possible?  Easy?   In VBA I would do something like `iif(len(%itemnotes%)<> 0, %itemnotes%,%description%)`

Comment: This is possible, but what is `%itemnotes%` and `%description%` exactly? Are they control sequences? Perhaps you could provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows your usage. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am hessitant to post the who TEX file as I am not sure how much is propiatory, but I can post the code that is printing the table:
\begin{tabularx}{19cm}{C{5mm} L{1.5cm} L{4.5cm} L{5cm} C{1cm} C{1cm} R{1.25cm} R{1.25cm} }
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Notes} & \textbf{Qt'y} &
    \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Amount}  \\ [0.5em]
<%foreach number%>
  <%runningnumber%> & <%number%> & <%description%> & <%itemnotes%>
  & <%qty%> & <%unit%> & <%sellprice%> & <%linetotal%>  \\
<%end number%>
\end{tabularx}
Hope this helps....

Comment: Any help would be great.   Basically what is happening is I need to print the <%description%> field if <%itemnotes%> if nul or zero length.  If there is something in <%itemnotes%> it will always contain everything in <%description%> and more.  This means I want <%itemnotes%> printing, unless it is blank, in that case print <%description%> instead, but only print one of them never both.

Comment: We still don't know what these variables look like where do you get them from? They're surely not hard coded, right? Do they exists in an external file? Do you generate the values/contents in a loop structure? So many unanswered questions.

Comment: Both fields are memo fields from a postgresql database.  This is a report being called by a php application.

Comment: So how do you use a PostgreSQL variable in LaTeX?

Comment: Not 100% sure, as the php code isn''t mine.

Comment: Then I think you're jumping ahead a little too far. First find out the interaction between PostgreSQL and PHP, then how that relates to LaTeX...

Comment: Ok I am lost.  What difference does that make to Latex?  I have two fields, both are text/string.  I want latex to print one of them (easy enough) unless it is blank or null in which case I want to print the other.   How the calling program comes up with them should not be important.

Comment: Here are my questions: (1) How do you insert the fields into a LaTeX variable? (2) How does your setup work? Do you have a PHP program that you run, and it extracts stuff from a PostgreSQL database and writes it to a CSV? Or does it write out a LaTeX file, or what? It's not clear what you mean by "this is a report [..] called by a PHP application." (3) Do you know anything about LaTeX? Can you provide a minimal example that shows your LaTeX setup? You have not made *any* this clear, *at all*.

Comment: 1:  Do not know, not my code.  PHP program written by someone else.
2:  The PHP code is located up on my Apache server and called from a web browser.
3:  I know a very little about LaTeX, learning more as I go.  I can eMail you the TEX file if you like.  Do not want to load someone elses code up here.  My eMail is gregory.west@dbwsys.mb.ca   If you eMail me, I can send you the TEX code including the area in question marked out so you can read it easily.

Comment: Sure, send *LaTeX code* to latex.abraces@gmail.com. I can't speak to any PHP code.

Comment: Good morning, eMailed you the code and a question.  Not sure if it got thrown in your spam box, My eMail is gregory.west@dbwsys.mb.ca